# Approving post edits: Links invisible

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, hyperlinks, suggested-edits

I was just approving some edits on SO, when I noticed that hyperlinks are almost invisible. This would make it pretty easy for spam links to slip through unnoticed. This can be seen very well in this example:

https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/51010

I'm using a current Chrome version.

Is it possible to emphasize new or changed links in the diffs displayed ?

Example:
[image]

Comment: black or dark-grey text, underline on hover. I definitely didn't see the link before mousing over it.

Comment: Update: added link to example.